# Undo editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the opposite of `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` in Visual Studio Code? i.e. undo the last selection it added.

In PhpStorm this is Alt+J and Alt+Shift+J is undo.

In Sublime, this is Ctrl+D, but I'm not sure if Sublime has the opposite.

Sometimes I get overzealous with my keybashing and have to go back one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `cursorUndo` (`cmd+u`) would do the trick, although it's not a dedicated command for this purpose.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6872

<s>I might just</s> [I did open a PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/6900) for it.

Comment: To be clear, this is *just* `cursorUndo` not `editor.action.cursorUndo`. Seems to work the way I want. Thank you! A dedicated command would be nice of symmetry, and it would prevent you from going back too far.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but I wanted to mention that I published an extension to solve this exact issue and add a few other features like being able to tab through your multiple cursors, remove all multi-cursor selections except the very last one, etc.

Check it out here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danseethaler.tab-through-selections

Answer (score 1):

**`Esc`** once will un-toggle multiple-cursors.

Pressing `Esc` again toggles the currently highlighted selection.

As others have said, `Cmd + U` will undo the last highlighted item if you accidentally select one too many.